# Behaviour of prolog '--' construct?

Tags: prolog

Good morning, 
I am stuck on a rule of a Prolog program found in OsmAnd. 
This is a simplified version:

```
dest(D) -- ['dest.ogg'|Ds] :- name(D, Ds).
```

I can't figure out what is the meaning of `--` as it is the first time I see such a construct in Prolog programs. It looks like a substitution read as follows: "`dest(D)` is the list obtained by replacing `Ds` in `['dest.ogg'|Ds]` if `name(D, Ds)`". 
Also, I tried to look for "--" in several Prolog manuals (e.g. SWI-Prolog) but I couldn't find anything related to such construct.

Any suggestion? Is it a custom construct?

Comment: Is `--` by any chance an operator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, the `--` part is **not specific to SWI**. It is an **operator**.  Probably in the file you will somewhere see:

```
:- op(900, xfx,--).
```

(or something similar)

So here the **operator `(--)/2` is defined**.  Next you can use `(--)/3` **as a predicate (or functor)** with *infix notation*. So in fact:

```
dest(D) -- ['dest.ogg'|Ds] :- name(D, Ds).
```

Is short for:

```
--(dest(D),['dest.ogg'|Ds]) :- name(D, Ds).
```

Which is a simple (well simple, it has a weird name) predicate definition. But by defining the operator with precedence 900 (at least in this answer), and mode `xfx` you can use it between two terms as an operator.

In Prolog, `is`, `+`, `-`, `*`, etc. are also operators. If you write `X is 2+2`, you have actually written `is(X,+(2,2))`. So here the `+` is replaced by a functor, and `is` is a predicate. There is thus *nothing special* about `is/2` either: it is simply a predicate that interprets a functor that describes the syntax tree of an expression that should be evaluated.

[This entry on *Operators*](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=operators) of the *SWI Prolog manual* explains operators in more depth.

Comment: Willem Van Onsem thank you very much for your punctual explanation and for the link to the SWI Prolog manual.

Indeed I found the following line in the first block of the program:

:- op(500, xfy,'--').

So you are definitely right, that is the definition of an operator. Now it is clear, thanks again!